# The use of concavity of $\log\det\left(u_{j\overline{k}}\right)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $F:\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be the function
$$
F\left(a_{1\overline{1}},a_{1\overline{2}},\ldots,a_{n\overline{n}}\right):=\log\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{1\overline{1}} & \cdots & a_{1\overline{n}}\\
 & \vdots\\
a_{n\overline{1}} & \cdots & a_{n\overline{n}}
\end{array}\right).
$$
Of course, in order to have $F$ well-defined, the domain of $F$
should be restricted to those $\left(a_{i\overline{j}}\right)$ with
$\det\left(a_{i\overline{j}}\right)>0$, for example positive Hermitian matrices.

It is well-known that $F$ is concave on the set of positive Hermitian
matrices. That is, for any positive Hermitian matrix $A$, we
have
$$
\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial a_{i\overline{j}}\partial a_{k\overline{l}}}\left(A\right)m_{i\overline{j}}m_{k\overline{l}}\leq0,\quad\left(1\right)
$$
where $\left(m_{i\overline{j}}\right)$ is any Hermitian matrix.

In many papers and literature,  [e.g here](http://gamma.im.uj.edu.pl/~blocki/publ/locest.pdf)  I often see that authors used the following
inequality 
$$
\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial a_{i\overline{j}}\partial a_{k\overline{l}}}\left(A\right)u_{i\overline{j}\gamma}u_{k\overline{l}\overline{\gamma}}\leq0,\quad\left(2\right)
$$
for a fixed $\gamma$. Here $u\in C^{3}$ be a real-valued function and $u_{i\overline{j}\gamma}$
denotes $\dfrac{\partial^{3}u}{\partial z_{i}\partial\overline{z_{j}}\partial z_{\gamma}}$.

My question: I cannot see where the conclusion (2) comes from.
Note that $\left(u_{i\overline{j}\gamma}\right)$ is not a Hermitian
matrix, for a fixed $\gamma$. It's not clear how to see (2) from (1).